# Is there a politeness change when replacing です with (っ)す?

Tags: grammar, politeness, formality

I've heard in video games and TV shows some male speakers using す or っす in place of です. For example, instead of "本はどこですか" they say "本はどこすか".  Does dropping the で make the sentence any less polite?  Are there situations where it would be appropriate to use です but not (っ)す?

Comment: 逆転裁判's 糸鋸刑事 comes to mind